# How to extract a certain value from an Array list that has multiple values for element

Tags: java

I have the following arraylist (below).  The first two values are for  Systolic and diastolic blood pressures.  I would like to ultimately code a method for obtaining the highest Systolic blood pressure for the ArrayList but I don't know how to isolate that particular value.

```
public class Blood {

    private int systolic;
    private int diastolic;

    private Day day;

    public Blood(int systolic, int diastolic, Day day)
    {
        this.systolic = systolic;
        this.diastolic = diastolic;
        this.day = day;
    }

    //setters and getter variables in this class
    public void setSystolic(int systolic)
    {
        this.systolic = systolic;
    }

    public int getSystolic()
    {
        return systolic;
    }

    //Method for determining the highest Systolic blood pressure
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%s%10s%20s",systolic,diastolic,day.toString());
    }
}

public class Day {
    private int num1;
    private int num2;
    private int num3;

    public Day(int num1, int num2, int num3)
    {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2= num2;
        this.num3 = num3;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%d%s%d%s%d",num1,"/", num2, "/", num3);
    }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
    Day cr = new Day(9,11,2013);
    System.out.println(cr.toString());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //Create and populate ArrayList
    ArrayList<Blood> mary = new ArrayList<Blood>();
    mary.add(new Blood(94,61, new Day(2,5,2013)));
    mary.add(new Blood(97,65, new Day(3,5,2013)));
    mary.add(new Blood(144,99, new Day(4,5,2013)));
    mary.add(new Blood(123,88, new Day(5,5,2013)));
    mary.add(new Blood(177,110, new Day(6,5,2013)));
    mary.add(new Blood(145,89, new Day(7,5,2013)));

    System.out.printf("%s%10s%10s\n", "Systolic", "Diastolic", "Date");
    for (int i = 0; i<mary.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(mary.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Initialize the max to 0, then loop over your blood objects, and if the current bllod's systolic is bigger than the max, then change the max. All you need is a max variable and a loop containing an if statement. You should figure that out by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  each element in my array has 3 values (Systolic, diastolic blood pressures and the Date) how do I specify a certain value in such an arraylist to loop?  I'm just not sure about the code for this.

Comment: If you never try anything, you'll never fail, but you'll never succeed either.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to ultimately code a method for obtaining the highest
>   Systolic blood pressure for the ArrayList

At first you need to implements Comparable interface to Blood class.

```
  public class Blood  implements Comparable<Blood>{


   int systolic;

   public int compareTo(Blood other){
     return other.systolic-this.systolic;
   }
```

After implements Comparable, than you can sort Blood class according to systolic at decending order.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 //Create and populate ArrayList
 ArrayList<Blood> mary = new ArrayList<Blood>();
 mary.add(new Blood(94,61, new Day(2,5,2013)));
 ........
 Collections.sort(mary);

 int highSystolic= mary.get(0).getSystolic();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your list using `Collections.sort` with a custom comparator and then get the first element.

```
Collections.sort(mary, new Comparator<Blood>(){
                   @Override
                   public int compare(Blood b1,Blood b2){
                           return b2.getSystolic() - b1.getSystolic();
                   }
});
Blood maxSystolic = mary.get(0);
```

Using a for loop, it will looks like :

```
Blood bMax = mary.get(0);
int maxSystolic = bMax.getSystolic();

for(int i = 1; i < mary.size(); i++){
   Blood b = mary.get(i);
   if(b.getSystolic() > bMax.getSystolic()){
      bMax = b;
      maxSystolic = bMax.getSystolic();
   }
}
```

If you want to get only the first, a loop will be more appropriate (runs in `O(n)`) while `Collections.sort` uses a merge sort which runs in `O(nlogn`).

But if you want to make multiple calls to get, let's say the 5 first elements with the max systolic value in your list, then it will be more efficient to sort it one time and get those after.

I would add that it's not a good idea of using your own `Day` class, because there is no checks in your code, we can do `Day cr = new Day(9999,11111,201300);`

Consider using the [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

Comment: You might be interested to know that there is a built-n max method in the standard Java API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29. So if you already have a comparator and wants to get the max, there is no need to code your own loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can get property of blood object from ArraList and you can find Maximum as given below

```
class Blood{
    int systolic;

    public int getSystolic() {
        return systolic;
    }

    public void setSystolic(int systolic) {
        this.systolic = systolic;
    }
}
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Blood> bloodList=new ArrayList<Blood>();
    Blood blood1=new Blood();
    Blood blood2=new Blood();
    blood1.setSystolic(10);
    blood2.setSystolic(5);
    bloodList.add(blood1);
    bloodList.add(blood2);

    Iterator<Blood> iterator=bloodList.iterator();  
    Blood temp=iterator.next();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Blood blood =iterator.next();
        if(temp.getSystolic()<blood.getSystolic())
            temp=blood;
    }
    System.out.println("Maximum="+temp.getSystolic());
}
}
```

Comment: You can also use Comparable